# How to get the domainname (name+TLD) from a URL in python

Tags: python, url, python-2.7, domain-name

I want to extract  the domain name(name of the site+TLD) from a list of URLs which may vary in their format.
for instance:
 Current state---->what I want

```
mail.yahoo.com------> yahoo.com
account.hotmail.co.uk---->hotmail.co.uk
x.it--->x.it
google.mail.com---> google.com
```

Is there any python code that can help me with extracting what I want from URL or should I do it manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is somewhat non-trivial, as there is no simple rule to determine what makes a for a valid public suffix (site name + TLD). Instead, what makes a public suffix is [maintained as a list at PublicSuffix.org](http://publicsuffix.org/).

A python package exists that queries that list (stored locally); it's called [`publicsuffix`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/publicsuffix/):

```
>>> from publicsuffix import PublicSuffixList
>>> psl = PublicSuffixList()
>>> print psl.get_public_suffix('mail.yahoo.com')
yahoo.com
>>> print psl.get_public_suffix('account.hotmail.co.uk')
hotmail.co.uk
```

Comment: Thanks.Can you tell me how should I use this package. Which file should I open after downloading it?

Comment: Either [run the `setup.py` file](http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html) or use an [python install tool (recommended)](http://guide.python-distribute.org/installation.html).

Comment: I am using eclipse IDE. which one is recommended?

Comment: An alternative to publicsuffix is the [tldextract](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract) module.

Comment: Yes, Loki mentioned it in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [public list](http://publicsuffix.org/) of TLD and CC TLD that is maintained.

This python project reads this list and compares your URL against this list.

```
https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract
```

Comment: @Martijn's answer covers this exactly.

Comment: Its an alternative python project. But I consider Martijn Pieters better.

Answer (score 1):

At this time I see six packages doing domain name splitting:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tldextract
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tld
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/publicsuffixlist
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/publicsuffix
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/publicsuffix2
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dnspy

They differ in the way they cache Public Suffix List data (only tldextract uses a JSON file, thereby sparing to parse the list on loading), in the strategy used to download that data, and in the structure they keep in memory (respectively: frozenset, set, set, dictionaries of labels, ditto, dictionary of names) which determines the search algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Using python tld

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tld

$ pip install tld

```
from tld import get_tld
print get_tld("http://www.google.co.uk/some-page/some-sub-page/")
'google.co.uk'
```

Comment: This is misleading. The tld is `uk`.